# Using list of implemented interface to store multiple types with ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, sql, linux, spring, postgresql

I try to create many to many relationship between `Album` class and `Artist` interface (which is implemented, currently by two classes: `Musician` and `Band`). To create relationship I created list of interface `Artist` in Album to avoid redundancy and implemented mentioned classes as shown below. Unfortunately, Spring fails to start due to:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.musesite.model.Band
```

Here is how I implemented Album class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="album")
public class Album {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "albums")
    private List<Artist> artists;
    @Embedded
    @Column(name="duration")
    private Duration duration;
    @Column(name="dateofrelease")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy", timezone="CET")
    private Date dateOfRelease;
    @Column(name="coverpath")
    private String coverPath;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    public Date getDateOfRelease() {
        return dateOfRelease;
    }
    public void setDateOfRelease(Date dateOfRelease) {
        this.dateOfRelease = dateOfRelease;
    }
    public String getCoverPath() {
        return coverPath;
    }
    public void setCoverPath(String coverPath) {
        this.coverPath = coverPath;
    }
}
```

Here is how I implemented Band class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="band")
public class Band implements Artist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "album_band",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "album_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "band_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Album> albums;
}
```

Here is how I implemented Musician class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="musician")
public class Musician implements Artist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name="dateofbirth")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy", timezone="CET")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "album_musician",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "album_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "musician_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Album> albums;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

`Artist` interface is just empty interface:

```
public interface Artist {
}
```

Comment: So you have Hibernate not knowing anything about Artist;  I don't think that's going to work.  I reckon you'll have to bring Hibernate in on that inheritance tree using one of the inheritance options ( https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance )

Comment: I tried to change `interface` to `class` `Artist`, annotate it with `MappedSuperclass` and add `protected` `id` to it and remove it from `Band` and `Musician` (so they could inherit it). Yet I get error: ```Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.musesite.model.Album.artists[com.musesite.model.Artist]```

Comment: Ah, unfortunately MappedSuperclass is the one that doesn't work here !  from the page : "Because the @MappedSuperclass inheritance model is not mirrored at the database level, it’s not possible to use polymorphic queries"     Try the "Joined Table" (aka Table-Per-Subclass) option.